# rails edit form showing wrong attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually Rails is doing what it's supposed to, but I want to change that.

my Trip form has a field for City name, in the code for the form it's listed as :city_id (the name is used to lookup the city before the trip is saved.)

Because this field is called :city_id when I pass @trip to the form to edit a trip, Rails displays the city id, not the city name. How can I change this?

City: 410

I want:

City: San Francisco, United States

trip form view:

```
<%= form_for @trip do |f| %>

<%= f.label :city_id, "City" %>
<%= f.text_field :city_id, options = { id: "navbar-search-input", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'San Francisco, United States' } %>

<br>

<%= f.label :start_date %>
<%= f.date_select :start_date %><br>

<%= f.label :end_date %>
<%= f.date_select :end_date %><br>


<%= f.submit "Add trip" %>
<% end %>
```

I convert the string name to the City id when I white list the params

```
:city_id => City.find_by_display(params[:trip][:city_id]).id
```

In my City model City.display = "City name, Country name"

So how can I get the edit form to display the City.display instead of City.id?

Comment: You are using same form for new and edit actions?

Comment: Yes, only change is the text on the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a *better approach would be to use a select to minimise your code* but if you don't want to change your UI then ***in your edit action you just need to do the reverse of what you are doing in new action. In your edit action just assign the value of city_id so when the form loads up it'll show up that string***

```
def edit
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  @trip.city_id = City.find(@trip.city_id).name #your logic to change city_id to its name
end
```